# ExtJS Drag with Scroll

Tags: extjs

I have an interface pretty much identical to one located in the ExtJS examples page:
[here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/organizer/organizer.html)

However, if you select items in the images panel, and then attempt to drag the scrollbar in any direction, the items are unselected and another drag instance is started. Makes sense on one level, but what if the user is trying to drag a large selection which involves panel scrolling?

**Are there any quick fixes to allow me to drag and scroll without losing the drag selection?**

Thanks!

Edit: Forgot to mention that this behaviour is reflected in the example listed above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those that are interested, I solved this by adding the following to the DataView:

```
        autoHeight:true, 
        autoWidth:true,
        style:'overflow:auto'
```

and added this to the Panel holding the DataView

```
        autoScroll:true
```